# React Native, need to conditionally import a library because get an exception in ExpoGo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm implementing **In-App-Purchases** in Expo, using `RevenueCat`.

Everything works fine in a build environment but in ExpoGo I get an exception if I import this library:

```
import Purchases, { PurchasesOffering } from 'react-native-purchases';
```

In my code I can detect when running in **ExpoGo**, so I would like to import this library only and if only running in NOT ExpoGo environment.

I tried this but is not working.

```
import { IsExpoGo, RevenueCatAPIKeys } from "./lib/constants";

if(!IsExpoGo){
  import Purchases, { PurchasesOffering } from 'react-native-purchases';
}
```

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

can try something like this

```
 const MODULE_NAME = !IsExpoGo ? require("react-native-purchases") : require("./lib/constants);
```

also take some help below link

https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web

Comment: How do I specify to import the following functions: Purchases, { PurchasesOffering } ?

Comment: can you try your approach with require import

Comment: I tried this:

import { IsExpoGo, RevenueCatAPIKeys } from "./lib/constants";
const PURCHASES = !IsExpoGo ? require("react-native-purchases") : '';

Then   if(!IsExpoGo)
    {
      PURCHASES.Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
}

In ExpoGo it works, because the module is not loaded, but when I publish my app crashes.

Comment: anny solution????